Use openocd to debug the RP2040 pico, and the hardware uses a daplink and a pico
I've now configured the development environment for openocd and Raspberry Pi on Windows, and can use openOCD to burn ELF with a daplink and a pico, and the hardware shows correctly, but I still can't debug this pico, especially with cortex-debugger on vscode. So, do you have to use two picos for pico debugging? I don't really understand.Or do I have to debug in a linux environment?
Here are the pictures I successfully downloaded.
enter image description here
But when I use cortex-debugger, I can't debug.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've joined tasks.json before, but it's still useless, maybe I don't have a deep understanding of the files in vscode's .vscode configuration
I hope that makers who have experience in windows development for RP2040 can help
I'd like to be able to successfully debug the pico with openocd using a daplink and a pico, especially with cortex-debugger
